# Can I open and make a popup run javascript on parent/host page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, popup, client-server

I'm developing some sort of a Javascript SDK that will open a popup of a page of mine. So everyone can call this javascript function and it will open a pop with my page, on my server. So host and popup are on different servers.

When the user do some things on my page (on popup), I need to use functions that are on the SDK on the host.

Is it possible to do this kind of thing? Or is it forbidden by default because it's too dangerous or could be an attack or something like that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be possible using
[easyXDM](https://github.com/oyvindkinsey/easyXDM).